# If $\cot^{-1} a < \epsilon $ can you tell me why $a> \cot \epsilon$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

If $\cot^{-1} a < \epsilon $ can you tell me why $a> \cot \epsilon$ instead of $a< \cot \epsilon$

Comment: $\cot x$ is a decreasing function

Answer (score 1):

It's wrong.

Try $a=1$ and $\epsilon=3.15.$
Because $$\cot^{-1}1<\pi<3.15,$$ but
$$1>\cot3.15$$ is wrong.

Comment: Iam actually confused. can you pls elaborate

Comment: @anirudh b I added something. See now.